# AJAx HTTP ERROR, can't add views to Drupal 7 site, same behavior on 2 different sites

Tags: ajax, javascript

I get these errors when creating views at every step, in Chrome errors says 200 in Firefox says 500...

I can get as far as having the view created, by ignoring the error, but then I can't add any fields, so it renders my Drupal site useless basically.

I have played around with Jquery versions and no solution seems to work.

Additionally, this behavior can be seen on 2 different website, identical...

Sites are both up to date Drupal 7, on status report everything is immaculate, they both run Boostrap theme but the admin Theme is Bartik

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with the hosting company....but they were great and changed to PHP 5.4(native) right away, fixed it.

Great job namecheap.com hosting, as usual, they are actually really good